# How to implement time-distributed dense (TDD) layer in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

In some deep learning models which analyse temporal data (e.g. audio, or video), we use a "time-distributed dense" (TDD) layer. What this creates is a fully-connected (dense) layer which is applied separately to every time-step.

[image]

In Keras this can be done using the [TimeDistributed wrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed), which is actually slightly more general. In PyTorch it's been [an open feature request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1927) for a couple of years.

How can we implement **time-distributed dense** manually in PyTorch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for **time-distributed dense** (and not time-distributed *anything else*), we can hack it by using a convolutional layer.

Look at the diagram you've shown of the TDD layer. We can re-imagine it as a convolutional layer, where the convolutional kernel has a "width" (in time) of exactly 1, and a "height" that matches the full height of the tensor. If we do this, while also making sure that our kernel is not allowed to move beyond the edge of the tensor, it should work:

```
self.tdd = nn.Conv2d(1, num_of_output_channels, (num_of_input_channels, 1))
```

You may need to do some rearrangement of tensor axes. The "input channels" for this line of code are in fact coming from the "freq" axis (the "image's y axis") of your tensor, and the "output channels" will indeed be arranged on the "channel" axis. (The "y axis" of the output will be a singleton dimension of height 1.)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the [discussion](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1927#issuecomment-311818189) you referred to:

> Meanwhile this [#1935](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1935) will make TimeDistributed/Bottle unnecessary for Linear layers.

For TDD layer, it would be applying the linear layer directly on the inputs with time slices.

```python
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: m = torch.nn.Linear(20, 30)

In [3]: input = torch.randn(128, 5, 20)

In [4]: output = m(input)

In [5]: print(output.size())
torch.Size([128, 5, 30])
```

The Following is a short illustration of the computational results

```python
In [1]: import torch                                                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: m = torch.nn.Linear(2, 3, bias=False) 
   ...:  
   ...: for name, param in m.named_parameters(): 
   ...:     print(name) 
   ...:     print(param) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                       
weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.3713, -0.1113],
        [ 0.2938,  0.4709],
        [ 0.2791,  0.5355]], requires_grad=True)

In [3]: input = torch.stack([torch.ones(3, 2), 2 * torch.ones(3, 2)], dim=0) 
   ...: print(input)                                                                                                                                                                          
tensor([[[1., 1.],
         [1., 1.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[2., 2.],
         [2., 2.],
         [2., 2.]]])

In [4]: m(input)                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[4]: 
tensor([[[-0.4826,  0.7647,  0.8145],
         [-0.4826,  0.7647,  0.8145],
         [-0.4826,  0.7647,  0.8145]],

        [[-0.9652,  1.5294,  1.6291],
         [-0.9652,  1.5294,  1.6291],
         [-0.9652,  1.5294,  1.6291]]], grad_fn=<UnsafeViewBackward>)
```

More details of the operation of [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) can be seen from the [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html#torch-matmul). Note, you may need to add another non-linear function  like `torch.tanh()` to get exact same layer as `Dense()` in `Keras`, where they support such non-linearity as keyword argument `activation='tanh'`.

For Timedistributed with e.g., CNN layers, maybe the snippet from the [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-pytorch-function-can-work-as-keras-timedistributed/1346/4) could be useful.

Comment: I do agree with you but this seems over-simplified... If it is indeed just a matrix multiplication, why people from Keras implemented a module for it?

Comment: Apparently, it is for more complex modules for which it is not as simple, like CNN.